# missing in props validation, react/prop-types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, next.js, react-props

I am setting up a Next-React app, which I am deploying on Netlify.

I am getting an error on Netlify's deploy log:
[Netlify deploy log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB84Y.png)
saying "Error: 'Component' is missing in props validation", "Error: 'pageProps' is missing in props validation" on my./pages/_app.js file.

[VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqkq5.png)

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
import React from 'react';

MyApp.propTypes = {

};

export default function MyApp({Component, pageProps}) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};
```

I have tried to add

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

which results in an error:
'PropTypes' is declared but its value is never read.
'PropTypes' is defined but never used.

I have tried to resolve this by doing

```
npm install --save prop-types --force
```

("--force" because there were a lot of dependency conflicts with storybook).
The issue persists.

Comment: MyApp.propTypes is empty, add Component and pageProps in there.

Comment: So the syntax would be "Component: React.PropTypes.something, pageProps: React.PropTypes.something". What would be the something be? Sorry I'm quite new to react.

Answer (score 2):

The following is what you need:

```
MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.shape({
    // your custom props here
  }),
};
```

`pageProps` may change depending of what you are fetching with `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, and so on.

As per the [NextJs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app):

> pageProps is an object with the initial props that were preloaded for
> your page by one of our data fetching methods, otherwise it's an empty
> object.